# HP t610 plotter disk failure

Tags: printer

I have two HP t610 plotters. One of them has a disk failure. Is there a tip to clone the first hard-disk to blank hard-disk?

Note that I have tried to clone using active boot disk ,  but it gives error. And another note, if I open the healthy hard drive it shows as if its not formatted. I think this is protection from HP on its hard disks.

Any solution ?

Comment: You need to clone the damaged disk or just to rescue your data?

Comment: i have the same data on the second harddrive , how to clone it.

Comment: If you're under Windows, you can check [this](http://lifehacker.com/5839753/the-best-disk-cloning-app-for-windows). And for Linux, [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5891933/the-best-disk-cloning-app-for-linux). I've tried CloneZilla wand was pretty satisfied.

Comment: when i try partition manager , hard disk appear to be null , but when i attached it to the plotter it power on normally

Comment: the problem that i am facing is an error when cloning under windows

Comment: I think it's an issue with the partition table of the disk, can you use a Linux live CD (like Ubuntu for example), open GParted and see if it can read the disk?
How about Windows? When you plug the disk, what does it say?

Comment: something like unallocated , i will try using dd tool in Linux , but i will check if g parted will read the part-ion table

Comment: So the partition table is damaged.. To recover your partition table, try [this software](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). I did not test it personally, but it may help you out of this situation.